# Why is a readline update needed when patching shellshock bash bug?

Tags: bash

The official SLES site:

https://download.suse.com/Download?buildid=nNXClbWqawg~

provides TAR files that contain "readline" packages besides the updated bash package.

**Question**: Why are the readline packages needed? Isn't the shellshock fixed with just updating only the bash package?

```
$ cd ssbash9SP4-i386-rev2
$ ls -1
bash-2.05b-305.21.7408.1.PTF.898762.i586.rpm
readline-4.3-306.19.7408.1.PTF.898762.i586.rpm
readline-devel-4.3-306.19.7408.1.PTF.898762.i586.rpm
$ rpm -qip bash-2.05b-305.21.7408.1.PTF.898762.i586.rpm 2>/dev/null | grep -i source
Source RPM  : bash-2.05b-305.21.7408.1.PTF.898762.src.rpm
$ rpm -qip readline-4.3-306.19.7408.1.PTF.898762.i586.rpm 2>/dev/null | grep -i source
Source RPM  : bash-2.05b-305.21.7408.1.PTF.898762.src.rpm
$ rpm -qip readline-devel-4.3-306.19.7408.1.PTF.898762.i586.rpm 2>/dev/null | grep -i source
Source RPM  : bash-2.05b-305.21.7408.1.PTF.898762.src.rpm
$
```

Comment: Are both build from the same source package? When sources are updated new builds are usually released for all binaries build from the source package, even if only one of them is affected by the change in the sources.

Comment: I updated the question, what does it mean that they come from the same source? - because they do!

Answer (score 1):

From the `rpm -qip` output you can see that all three binary RPM packages are built from the same source package: `bash-2.05b-305.21.7408.1.PTF.898762.src.rpm`

This means that when the source for any of these are updated, there will be a new version of this `.src.rpm` file. The new `.src.rpm` file is then used to build all three binary packages. Hence there will be an updated version of all three (and possibly some more binary packages, which are not installed on your system.)

If you know exactly what was changed and that it doesn't affect the `readline` packages, you could refrain from updating the `readline` packages. However even if the `readline` packages happen to be identical to the previous version (appart from the version number), then you could still cause breakage by mixing versions, if any version number checks happen to be a bit too pedantic about which version is required.

My recommendation thus is to update all three of them even if it might not be strictly required. It tends to be more work maintaining a system, if you pick and choose among updates, and less work if you simply install all the updates made available for your chosen distribution.